# Compare arrays and push data to index locations

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following usecase ,i have two arrays like the below

```
arr1=[{room_no:1,bed_no:'1A'},
      {room_no:1,bed_no:'1B'},
      {room_no:2,bed_no:'2A'},
      {room_no:3,bed_no:'3A'},
      {room_no:3,bed_no:'3B'},
      {room_no:4,bed_no:'4A'}]

 arr2=[
       { patient_details:[{name:'patient1',age:22}],
         patient_room_details:[{room_no:1,bed_no:'1A'}],
         status:'occupied'
       },
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:1,bed_no:'1B'},
         status:'available'
       },
       {  patient_details:[{name:'patient2',age:32}],
          patient_room_details:[{room_no:2,bed_no:'2A'}],
          status:'occupied'
       }
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:3,bed_no:'3A'},
         status:'cleaning'
       },
      ]
```

Iam trying to compare the room_no and bed_no from first array with second array patient_room_details . If the match is found Iam pushing the matched object to an result array with patient_details,patient_room_details and status . If no match is found I need to push only status as AVAILABLE .

Iam not able to push the status as AVAILABLE , if the match is not found , Any help would be appreciated

and the final result would be like

```
result=[
       { patient_details:[{name:'patient1',age:22}],
         patient_room_details:[{room_no:1,bed_no:'1A'}],
         status:'occupied'
       },
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:1,bed_no:'1B'},
         status:'available'
       },
       {  patient_details:[{name:'patient2',age:32}],
          patient_room_details:[{room_no:2,bed_no:'2A'}],
          status:'occupied'
       },
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:3,bed_no:'3A'},
         status:'cleaning'
       },
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:3,bed_no:'3B'},
         status:'available'
       },
       { patient_room_details:[{room_no:4,bed_no:'4A'},
         status:'available'
       },
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can be combined to efficiently compare `arrays` using `keys`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const rooms = [{room_no: 1, bed_no: '1A'}, {room_no: 1, bed_no: '1B'}, {room_no: 2, bed_no: '2A'}, {room_no: 3, bed_no: '3A'}, {room_no: 3, bed_no: '3B'}, {room_no: 4,bed_no: '4A'}]
const patients = [{patient: {name: 'patient1', age: 22}, room: {room_no: 1,bed_no: '1A'}, status: 'occupied'}, {room: {room_no: 1, bed_no: '1B'}, status: 'available'}, {patient: {name:'patient2',age:32}, room: {room_no:2,bed_no: '2A'}, status:'occupied' }, {room: {room_no: 3, bed_no:'3A'}, status: 'cleaning'}]

// Room Status.
const roomStatus = (rooms, patients) => (m => rooms.map(r => m.get(`${r.room_no} ${r.bed_no}`) || {room: r, status: 'available'}))(new Map(patients.map(x => [`${x.room.room_no} ${x.room.bed_no}`, x])))

// Output.
const output = roomStatus(rooms, patients)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```